# Application.Match with number stored as text

Tags: vba

I am getting a type mismatch error with the code below. ENT.Cells(2,1) contains a number - 709150 - which is stored as text.

```
    Dim test As Long
    test = Application.Match(ENT.Cells(2, 1), RDS.Range("A:A"), 0)
```

If I change the argument to a number, it works. However, I cannot pass a number as we have some "0xxxxx" codes

```
    Dim test As Long
    test = Application.Match(709150, RDS.Range("A:A"), 0)
```

Comment: You are getting the type mismatch because the Match is returning an error as the value is not found in the column.  Change `test` to a variant and test if it is an error before doing anything with it.  But to your problem, if your values in `ENT.Cells(2, 1)` are stored as text then `RDS.Range("A:A")` will also need to store everything as text.

Comment: @Scott Craner - Thanks! Indeed it was the problem with `RDS.Range("A:A")`.